# how to hide scroll bar on mobile terminal (webkit)

Tags: css

[image]

i try to use ::-webkit-scrollbar ,but it's did't work
It is achievable when I close the mobile terminal

Comment: why would you want to do this? If the content of the screen is more than the height of the  device, scroll bar should appear. Still if you need this, you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Answer (score 0):

if think this is what you are looking for

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar{
   display:none !impoirtant;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**